# How do I download photos from icloud photo library onto my PC?

Tags: icloud

My iCloud storage has run out. I want to transfer all photos/videos to my windows laptop, but when I log in to my iCloud account online cannot view any photos or videos in order to download. I also don't know if I can now turn off iCloud photo library without losing files, as I don't have sufficient phone storage (at least until I can download these photos/videos and delete them!)